# How can I repeat all of this code under one circumstance and only some of it under another?

Tags: c++

Sorry for the vague title - wasn't sure how to phrase it without just showing what I'm trying to do.

If the user enters '2' (No), I'd like all of the code you see here to repeat so that the user can re-enter their name. In the current version of my code, that works fine. The problem occurs when the user enters any number other than '1' or '2'. If they enter 3 or anything else, I'd like the terminal to print "Invalid entry" and then repeat all of the code from line 11 downwards. My problem is that I can't figure out how to get these two behaviors to be capable of working at the same time.

```
std::string assign_name() 
{
    std::string name;
    int confirm_name = 0;

    do {
        std::cout << "\nWhat is your name?\n\n";
        std::cin >> name;

        std::cout << "\n\nYour name is " << name << "?\n";
        std::cout << "1. Yes\n";
        std::cout << "2. No\n\n";
        std::cin >> confirm_name;
    } while (confirm_name != 1);

    return name;
}
```

I've tried organizing the code in a bunch of different ways, but the solution just isn't coming to me. Any help's appreciated - thanks.

Edit: Wrapping the last part of the function in its own separate do statement worked perfectly.

Comment: Wrap liness 11 to 14 in another `do{} while(confirm_name != 1 && confirm_name != 2);`.

Comment: The code isn't checking for `cin` going into an error state.

Comment: You can use a `goto: statement` is what I think you are asking, or an `if else`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an if else statement so that it can continue if condition is not met. In your code u did not specify what should happen when the answer is not 1 or 2

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you can use if / then / else.  There are a lot of different ways you can use control statement (if / then, do / while, etc..) to achieve the desired behavior...

```
  std:string name, confirm_name;
  bool done;
  std::cout << "\nWhat is your name?\n\n";
  do
    {
      std::cin >> name;
      std::cout << "\n\nYour name is " << name << "?\n";
      std::cout << "1. Yes\n";
      std::cout << "2. No\n\n";
      std::cin >> confirm_name;
      if (confirm_name == "1")
      {
          done = true;
      }
      else if (confirm_name != "2")
      {
         std::cout << "invalid value";
      }
    }    
  while (!done);
```

Comment: Problems, possibly an Infinite loop, if the user inputs a non-numeric for `confirm_name`.

Answer (score 0):

1 - After the user confirms their name, add an if statement to check whether their input matches 1 or 2, if not, then send invalid entry message

2 - Set the while loop to iterate again if the user response did not match 1 or 2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string assign_name() 
{
    std::string name;
    int confirm_name = 0;

    do {
        std::cout << "\nWhat is your name?\n\n";
        std::cin >> name;

        std::cout << "\n\nYour name is " << name << "?\n";
        std::cout << "1. Yes\n";
        std::cout << "2. No\n\n";
        std::cin >> confirm_name;


        if (confirm_name != 1 && confirm_name != 2)
        {

            std::cout << "Invalid entry\n";

        }
    } while (confirm_name != 1 || confirm_name !=2);

    return name;
}

int main()
{
assign_name();
}
```